# Choose bases of V and W so that the linear transformation L: V -> W can be represented as identity matrix extended by zero-rows and zero-columns

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The textbook I'm using states that every linear transformation L: V -> W can be written as

$$L = \begin{pmatrix}I_r & 0\\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
where I equals the identity matrix and r equals the rank of the transformation.

How would you generally choose the bases of V and W so that the linear transformation can be written like this? I've thought about this for a while but can't seem the find any logic in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n = \dim V$ and $m = \dim W$. By the rank-nullity theorem, the nullspace of $T$ has dimension $n -r$. Choose a basis for the nullspace of $T$, and denote the basis vectors by $v_{r+1}, \ldots, v_n$. Extend this to a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ of $V$. It can be shown (see below) that $T(v_{1}), \ldots, T(v_{r})$ are linearly independent. Let $w_i  = T(v_{i})$ for $i = 1, \ldots r$. Then extend $w_1, \ldots, w_r$ to a basis $w_1, \ldots, w_m$ of $W$.

Now, let's confirm that $T(v_{1}), \ldots, T(v_{r})$ are linearly independent. Suppose not. Then there exists $c_1, \ldots, c_r$, not all zero, such that
$$
0 = c_1 T(v_1) + \cdots + c_r T(v_r) = T( c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_r v_r).
$$
Hence, $c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_r v_r$ is in the nullspace of $T$. Since $v_{r+1}, \ldots, v_n$ span the nullspace of $T$, there exist $c_{r+1}, \ldots, c_n$ (possibly all zero) such that
$$
c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_r v_r = c_{r+1} v_{r+1} + \cdots + c_{n} v_n,
$$
contrary to the linear independence of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a basis of the kernel is $e_{r+1},e_{r+2},\dots$. Complete the basis to a basis of $V$ by $e_1,e_2,\dots$. Consider the basis $f_1=L(e_1),f_2=L(e_2),f_r=L(e_r),f_{r+1},f_{r+2},\dots$ in $W$, where $f_{r+1},f_{r+2}$ etc. are chosen arbitrarily to complete a basis in $W$. In the bases $\{e_i\}$ in $V$  and $\{f_j\}$ in $W$, $L$ has the desired matrix.